# C# Losing values in a nested List

Tags: c#, list, exception, collections

I'm incurring a really weird problem with my Nested List of int (`List<List<int>>`). At some point after I put over 1 million list's in it they all loose they're values i.e they have 0 elements in them .. Really weird right? I suspected that I'm putting too much list's in it. However I putted an if statement that will check if the nested list length is exactly 1 million and added a break point in it. It ended up that exceeding the nested list capability wasn't the case, it's something that completely messes with my head. I will post the code here so I can try to explain

```
        //it will iterate 8^8 times - 16.7 million times
        private static List<List<int>> minMinatRed = new List<List<int>>();
        private static List<List<int>> minMinataKolona = new List<List<int>>();
        var tempHodove = new List<Tuple<bool, int[]>>();
        int novMinatRed = red;
        int novaMinataKolona = kolona;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVariations; i++)
        {
            tempHodove.Clear();
            var hodove = UpdateList(novMinatRed, novaMinataKolona);
            int x = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            {
                result[j] = tempArr[x % size];
                x /= size;
            }
            for (int k = result.Length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                tempHodove.Add(hodove[result[k]]);
            }
            bool trueValue = tempHodove.Any(c => c.Item1);
            while (trueValue)
            {
                foreach (var hod in tempHodove.Where(hod => hod.Item1))
                {
                    novMinatRed += hod.Item2[0];
                    novaMinataKolona += hod.Item2[1];
                    minatRed.Add(novMinatRed);
                    minataKolona.Add(novaMinataKolona);
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                if (novMinatRed == kraenRed && novaMinataKolona == krainaKolona)
                {
                    if (minCount > count)
                    {
                        minCount = count;
                    }
                    minMinatRed.Add(minatRed);
                    minMinataKolona.Add(minataKolona);
                }
                hodove = UpdateList(novMinatRed, novaMinataKolona);
                tempHodove.Clear();
                for (int k = result.Length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                {
                    tempHodove.Add(hodove[result[k]]);
                }
                trueValue = tempHodove.Any(c => c.Item1);
            }
            if (minMinatRed.Count == 1000000)
            {

            }
            minataKolona.Clear();
            minatRed.Clear();
            count = 0;
            novMinatRed = nachalenRed;
            novaMinataKolona = nachalnaKolona;
        }
```

The problem is in the `minMinatRed` and `minMinataKolona` list's as you can see there is only place where I add some values in them :

```
if (novMinatRed == kraenRed && novaMinataKolona == krainaKolona)
{
     if (minCount > count)
     {
          minCount = count;
     }
     minMinatRed.Add(minatRed); //here
     minMinataKolona.Add(minataKolona); //and here
}
```

Well once the break point is triggered in the :

```
if (minMinatRed.Count == 1000000){ }
```

I started checking what's going on.I found out that once the code reaches this point :

```
minataKolona.Clear();
minatRed.Clear();
```

It doesn't only wipes the `minatRed` values but it also erases the `minMinatRed` values, same goes for `minataKolona` and `minMinataKolona`..
Also once it goes back into the loop and add's some values to `minatRed` and `minataKolona` it also add's the same values to the nested list's more specifically here :

```
foreach (var hod in tempHodove.Where(hod => hod.Item1))
{
     novMinatRed += hod.Item2[0];
     novaMinataKolona += hod.Item2[1];
     minatRed.Add(novMinatRed);  //here
     minataKolona.Add(novaMinataKolona);  //and here
     count++;
     break;
}
```

Now since we previously wiped all the values from `minatRed` it will obviously have nothing in it and once we add 1 item to it, it has 1 item in it (lol).. now the thing is that it also adds this exact 1 item into EVERY single one of the List's in the `minMinatRed` nested list i.e all the 1 million lists have length 1 and also just 1 duplicate variable in them. That's what I was able to find about my current problem, however I have no clue why this is happening or how can I fix it. I have also read some question and answer's written by Mystical who's a StackOverFlow user too. Where they discussed branch predictions, I'm not sure if that's my case but it might be something related. Any suggestions and explanations are welcome. English is not my native language..

**Update 1** forgot to include initialization of `minataKolona` and `minatRed` && numberOfVariations

```
    private static readonly List<int> minatRed = new List<int>();
    private static readonly List<int> minataKolona = new List<int>();
    private static readonly double numberOfVariations = Math.Pow(size, size);
```

**Update 2** Include the `UpdateList` method

```
 private static List<Tuple<bool, int[]>> UpdateList(int red, int kolona)
    {
        var vsichkiHodove = new List<Tuple<bool, int[]>>()
        {
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nadqsno(red, 1) && Napred(kolona, 2), new[]
            {
                +1,
                +2
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nadqsno(red, 2) && Napred(kolona, 1), new[]
            {
                +2,
                +1
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nalqvo(red, 1) && Napred(kolona, 2), new[]
            {
                -1,
                +2
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nalqvo(red, 2) && Napred(kolona, 1), new[]
            {
                -2,
                +1
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nadqsno(red, 2) && Nazad(kolona, 1), new[]
            {
                +2,
                -1
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nalqvo(red, 2) && Nazad(kolona, 1), new[]
            {
                -2,
                -1
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nadqsno(red, 1) && Nazad(kolona, 2), new[]
            {
                +1,
                -2
            }),
            new Tuple<bool, int[]>(Nalqvo(red, 1) && Nazad(kolona, 2), new[]
            {
                -1,
                -2
            }),
        };
        return vsichkiHodove;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an int to index a very large array.  Use a long instead.

Comment: it will iterate 8^8 times - 1.67 million times so it shouldn't be a problem for int

Comment: Are you showing all relevant code? I don't see where `minataKolona` is assigned.

Comment: not to nit-pick but 8^8 is 16777216

Comment: correct, still not a problem for int

Comment: The problem is when you clear `minatRed` the lists inside `minMinatRed` are cleared too?

Comment: where do you set size and numberofvariations? (its not included)

Comment: yes that's the problem, also when i add values to `minatRed` they instantly get added to `minMinatRed` also added `numberOfVariations` to the question

Comment: I think you have more code than you're showing.. its really hard when you just show snippets

Comment: Could you show the code for `UpdateList(novMinatRed, novaMinataKolona)`?

Comment: Why are you testing minMinatRed.Count == 1000000 instead of minMinatRed.Count >= 1000000?  If trueValue is never set to false count can be very large.  You should add a better method for exiting the while loop.

Comment: I do have more code but im sure that all the magic is happening here. Since when it reaches `minatRed.Clear();` it just clears the nested list that means the other parts of my code aren't important.. i dont have any function that can do such a thing

Comment: @jdweng i wrote that in my question it's just for testing purposes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `List<T>` is a type by reference, therefore, when you add the lists `minatRed` and `minataKolona` to `minMinatRed` and `minMinataKolona` respectively, you're not creating a new (cloned) list.

All lists in `minMinatRed` (`minMinataKolona`) points to the same one: `minatRed` (`minataKolona`), so when you clear `minatRed` (or `minataKolona`), all lists in `minMinatRed` (or `minMinataKolona`) are cleared too, since actually are the same list.

You can solve this declaring `minatRed` and `minataKolona` inside the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVariations; i++)
{
    var minatRed = new List<int>();
    var minataKolona = new List<int>();
    ...
```

And of course you can't empty the lists:

```
//minataKolona.Clear();  Comment this lines or just remove it
//minatRed.Clear();      Comment this lines or just remove it
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arturo.  Normally the code would look something like code below.  I can't tell from your code where the equivalent to newRow (novMinatRed) is ever being cleared.

```
            List<List<int>> minMinatRed = new List<List<int>>();
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                 List<int> newRow = new List<int>();
                 minMinatRed.Add(newRow);
                 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                 {
                     newRow.Add(j);
                 }
             }
```